# Use jquery to change the class of a target element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attr

I have a List `li` of elements that I used `.toArray()`. I now need to loop through them to find the desired element and change its style Class.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I cannot seem to get the class of the index item, but I can retrieve the `innerHTML` no problem.

```
var viewsIndex = $('#viewsList li').toArray()
        for(i=0; i < viewsIndex.length; i++) {
            if(viewsIndex[i].innerHTML == selectedTab) {

                console.log(viewsIndex[i].attr('style')); //This does NOT work
                console.log(viewsIndex[i].innerHTML); //This does work
            }
            else
            {


            }
        }
```

Once I target the Element, I want to use `.removeClass` and `.addClass` to change the style.

Answer (score 5):

This is the DOM object which doesn't have jQuery functions:

```
viewsIndex[i]
```

This is the jQuery object which has the `attr` function:

```
$(viewsIndex[i]).attr('style')
```

Anyway, your code could be a lot simpler with this:

```
$('#viewsList li').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML == selectedTab;
}).removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
```

Comment: Please use `$(this).html()` :-). jQuery doesn't normalize everything for you to use `innerHTML` :P

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, this is so wrong, jQuery wasn't meant to replace javascript(as it is javascript...), it helps you doing things easier, if you are over using jQuery- meaning you're using verbose jQuery functions instead of using js native functions, you're doing something wrong. **jQuery- write less do more**, isn't it? please read the [_"Know Your DOM Properties and Functions"_](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Comment: Dude. `innerHTML` works differently across browsers. jQuery normalizes everything for you. If you're using jQuery, at least use it when necessary --- this case is a necessary one.

Comment: @gdoron with that logic why wrap the element to use .attr() when .getAttribute() is faster, well supported and not overly verbose in comparison to the jQuery method.

Comment: @rlemon, I think `getAttribute` has some problems in some browsers, anyway I do use `getAttribute` if I know which browsers I'm targeting. with innerHTML I've never heard or had problems. see this in the source code of jQuery's attr: `attrHooks`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to call jQuery function on `DOM` object convert it to `jQuery` object first.

Change

```
viewsIndex[i].attr('style')
```

To

```
$(viewsIndex[i]).attr('style')
```

Comment: I just tried `var $item = viewsIndex[i];
                console.log($item.attr('style'));` with no luck.

Comment: @Rob, well... This isn't the code he wrote in his answer... anyway, you're doing it wrong, use the `filter` function.

Comment: You did not convert the element to jQuery object try this, var $item = $(viewsIndex[i]); console.log($item.attr('style'));

Comment: Just saw that error on my part. thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you use `.each()`?

```
$('#viewLists li').each(function(i){
    if($(this).html == selectedTab){
       $(this).removeClass('foo').addClass('bar');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the elements using jQuery `each` and then access them as `$(this)`. This way you'll have access to jQuery methods on each item.

```
$('#viewsList li').each(function(){

    var element = $(this);

    if(element.html() == selectedTab){
        console.log(element.attr('style')
    } else {

    }
}
```